# Using Recyclerview with DiffUtil.ItemCallback doesn't scroll to top?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-diffutils

I do search of items and every time I fetch from server
When I search "o" it works and then "ot" it works again and as a result of "o" search I have let's say 20 items and in case "ot" I have 10 items 
which are part of that 20 items and I do remove t in EditText it shows 20 items only the recyclerview scroll indicator is in the middle 
Here is my Code for diffUtil

```
ListAdapter<Asset, SearchAdapter.ViewHolder>(object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Asset>() {

    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Asset, newItem: Asset): Boolean {
        return oldItem.assetId == newItem.assetId && oldItem.originalTitle ==newItem.originalTitle
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Asset, newItem: Asset): Boolean {
        return oldItem == newItem
    }

}




  viewModel.searchAssets.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
      searchAdapter.submitList(it)
    })
```

Here you can see the video I have filmed
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ia5y9TtL0PSAM1M4hVBILWcdSK1BDyKI?usp=sharing

Answer (score 6):

I want to answer my own question as I got an answer from Yiğit

> submit list has another overload which receives a callback when list
> applied  you can use that one and just call rv.scrollToPosition(0)

Here is my code:

```
searchAdapter.submitList(it) {
   viewBinding.searchList.scrollToPosition(0)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behaviour for `DiffUtil`. If you want to scroll to the top of your `RecyclerView` after the result have been updated, you can call `layoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(0, 0)`, or `recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0)`

Comment: where should I call layoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(0, 0) ?

Comment: After your recyclerview's adapter has been updated (i.e. `notifyDataSetChanged()`), or after you've called `dispatchUpdatesTo(...)` on your `DiffResult`

Comment: I don't call notifyDataSetChanged()  and I have submitList() in adapter and  DiffUtil.ItemCallback<>() and my Adapter extends
ListAdapter<Asset, SearchAdapter.ViewHolder>(diffCallback)

Comment: I'm not familiar with this `SearchAdapter`, is it part of a library? Try calling `scrollTo...` after you've called `submitList(...)`?

Comment: SearchAdapter is my adapter